# using ng-repeat with api json in a for-loop

Tags: angularjs, arrays, api, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing a mini app using angularjs that would grab data from a news api. I have succeeded in getting an array of 10(just the amount i want) articles from the array of 10 news sources( all provided by the api) using a for-loop(below). The problem is that the ng-repeat in the view only displays the last iteration of the loop. How can i get it to display all the iterations?

here is the controller:

```
angular.module('newsApp',[])
  .controller('newsController',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

    var index = 0;
    var sortby = ['top','latest','popular'];

    $http.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en').then(function(response){
      var sourceIdArray = [];
      var articlesArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        $scope.getId = response.data.sources[i].id;
        sourceIdArray.push($scope.getId);




         $http.get(' https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + sourceIdArray[i] + '&apiKey=53bec2b512724f58b92203f0f7e93dc1').then(function(response){
        $scope.comits = response.data.articles
        articlesArray.push($scope.comits);
      });

      }


    })



  }])
```

The loop gives me all the required articles but i don't know how to write the ng-repeat to display all the data instead of only the last iteration

and the html:

```
<div class="row rowdiv" ng-repeat="comit in comits" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img ng-src="{{comits[$index].urlToImage}}" alt="">
          <h3><a ng-href="{{comits[$index].url}}">{{comits[$index].title}}</a></h3>
          <p>{{comits[$index].description}}</p>
          <h5>{{result}}    {{comits[$index].author}}</h5>
          <h6 class="pull-right">{{comits[$index].publishedAt}}</h6>


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img ng-src="{{comits[$index +1].urlToImage}}" alt="">
          <h3><a ng-href="{{comits[$index +1].url}}">{{comits[$index +1].title}}</a></h3>
          <p>{{comits[$index + 1].description}}</p>
          <h5>{{result}}   {{comits[$index + 1].author}}</h5>
          <h6 class="pull-right">{{comits[$index +1].publishedAt}}</h6>


        </div>

      </div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Reference the current item in the ng-repeat using comit in your template rather than comits[$index].

Comment: I tried that already but it did not work

Comment: this usage of `ng-repeat` is **very inefficient**.  for an array of 10 items, you are looping through the array 10 times, and outputting the next two items on half the loops, which means that you actually end up accessing the array 20 times for 10 items.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the articles into the articlesArray with  articlesArray.push($scope.comits);

You need to make articlesArray a member of $scope, then access it with ng-repeat. $scope.comits only contains the last article retrieved based on your code.

Or declare comits as $scope.comits = [] then change  $scope.comits = response.data.articles to  $scope.comits.push(response.data.articles)